# Resize an Image in Python

Tags: python, image, scipy, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I have an jpg image of 2500 pixels by 2500 pixels.

How can I save it as 4cm height by 3cm width with 600 dpi?

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('test.jpg')
new = img.resize((600,650), Image.NEAREST)  ###Not complete!
new.save('result.jpg','JPEG',dpi=(600,600))
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you not simply want to resize the width and height of the image as follows?

```
width = math.ceil((3.0 * 600.0) / 2.54)
height = math.ceil((4.0 * 600.0) / 2.54)

print "%u x %u" % (width, height)
```

Giving:

```
709 x 945
```